# Why does Xcode simulator sometimes get stuck on a black screen?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator

[image: the error]

```
Details

The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)
Domain: NSMachErrorDomain
Code: -308
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-05-25 14:19:36 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 29517;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-308";
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSMachErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 0;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0 (Build 22A8380)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-05-25T19:49:36+05:30
```

Sometimes while I build and run my app, Xcode is stuck at "Launching" and the simulator pops up with a black screen. On quitting the simulator, Xcode throws an error (image attached).

**I have tried -**

1. Clearing DerivedData
2. Reinstalling Xcode
3. Resetting macOS
4. Switching devices
5. Removing excluded architectures parameter from all targets

Any idea how to fix this? This happens 1 out of 2 times and is very frustrating.
This happened on previous versions of Xcode as well.

Xcode version 14.3 (14E222b)
macOS Ventura 13.0
MacBook Pro 14 inch, 2023 (M2 Max)

Comment: Probably an Apple bug. Submit it to them